# WSO2 Manager version 4.1.O needs restart after publishing new APIs

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

WSO2 API Manager needs to restart after creating and publishing a new API in the new version (4.1.O). In old versions, there is no need to restart it.

Comment: What is the issue you are getting? API is not deployed to one of the servers?

Comment: What is your deployment pattern? Do you have separate GW and Publisher nodes?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a distributed API Manager deployment (not an all-in-one setup)? I suspect there could be a misconfiguration between the Control plane and the gateway node. Better to verify the configurations first (refer [1]).

In a distributed setup, gateway nodes listen to a JMS topic in the control plane. when API is deployed, gateway gets an event and after that, it queries the CP and gets the API-related artifacts. I suspect this CP->GW event is not reaching the gateway. As a result, APIs are not deployed in the gateway and cannot invoke it.

Gateway node does not keep the API artifacts stored. When there is a restart, gateway node calls the control plane directly and gets the available API-related artifacts and deploys them. That is why it works when you restart the gateway.

This is the new event-based mechanism we use in the APIM versions 3.2 onwards. That is why it worked in old versions.

[1] https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/install-and-setup/setup/distributed-deployment/deploying-wso2-api-m-in-a-distributed-setup/

Comment: [apim.throttling]
service_url = "https://[control-plane-LB-host]/services/"
throttle_decision_endpoints = ["tcp://control-plane-1-host:5672", "tcp://control-plane-2-host:5672"]

[[apim.throttling.url_group]]
traffic_manager_urls = ["tcp://control-plane-1-host:9611"]
traffic_manager_auth_urls = ["ssl://control-plane-1-host:9711"]

[[apim.throttling.url_group]]
traffic_manager_urls = ["tcp://control-plane-2-host:9611"]
traffic_manager_auth_urls = ["ssl://control-plane-2-host:9711"]

can please explain control plane 1 and 2 and LB, I am confused in it.

Comment: This deployment has two control plane nodes for high availability and a load balancer to front these two nodes.  If you do not need high availability, you can configure single control plane node. (this doc has that configuration as well.)